# Sorting FileList data without form inputs

Tags: jquery, arrays, sorting, filelist

I'm rather new to understanding Javascript, Jquery and PHP. At this point I've spent close to 80 hours working on understanding this one fix and I'm hoping to gain some insight. I'm working with [this](https://github.com/weixiyen/jquery-filedrop) drag and drop image upload functionality and I need to sort the image items within the FileList object alphanumerically base on their local filename to coincide with the organizational system of a photograph database. I understand that the FileList object is read-only, so I'm assuming this is achieved by adding these items into their own array to sort or compare.

Using this code,

```
files = e.dataTransfer.files;
newFiles = Array.from(files).map(({name}) => name);
            newFiles.sort();
    console.log(files);
    console.log(newFiles);
```

I was able to plug the file names into their own array, but I'm not sure how to proceed in comparing this new list of items to their original `FileList` counterpart for sorting. [Output.](https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/5779/R7fP8A.jpg) (Notice how the last three items of the `FileList` object (files) returns unsorted and `newFiles`, while sorted, only contains the name data.)

I've tried utilizing this `.slice` method:

```
files = [].slice.call(files);
```

But I can't seem to get the code to fire. The images upload like normal without being sorted.

Same goes for this method:

```
files = [...e.dataTransfer.files].sort();
```

I've also attempted using [MDN's](https://fuzzytolerance.info/blog/2019/07/19/The-better-way-to-do-natural-sort-in-JavaScript/) recommended code:

```
files.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, navigator.languages[0] || navigator.language, {numeric: true, ignorePunctuation: true}));
```

but when I attempt to implement this fix, the console returns that [LocaleCompare is not a function](https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/5682/r0Ryhg.jpg).

I have also looked into using Lauri Rooden's [natural compare lite](https://github.com/litejs/natural-compare-lite) and Boris Moore's [jsrender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender), but I don't understand how to go about implementing these plugins.

I started writing an iterator to determine if the two arrays could be compared and sorted as such, and I'm honestly just wondering if I'm on the right track?

```
for (i=0; i < files.length; i++) {
                      if (files.name[i] === newFiles[i]) {
                 files.splice(i, 1, newFiles[i]) }
             else{i++;
       }
```

I'm having some issues with an internal server [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgopk.jpg) in the PHP, but if the regular code works with the error in place, could this be something that stands in the way of the `FileList` object being sorted?

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/D_Train/nyfkqp9j/9/) a fiddle with the code. The PHP is commented out below HTML so the code doesn't run at all & the Javascript iframe is split into 3 sections separated by comments. I know this post is long and there are lots of outside sources, but I wanted be sure I was thorough in my explanation. If you have any advice for an aspiring web dev (other than to quit ^_^;), I would greatly appreciate it! Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: "I need to sort the image items within the FileList object". Why?

Comment: I would like for the image files to be sorted alphanumerically by name. This project is for local use and isn't intended for the public. The files uploaded to the current build combine letters, numbers, and a file extension. I know I can't sort the FileList itself without first committing its objects to a new array

Comment: That doesn't answer the question "why?"  It's possible you don't know, because there's no need to sort that list.

Comment: I amended the original post to hopefully better make sense of the situation, but being I am still new to the trade, I'd argue you're probably right! Ha! 

I have a database of photographs that possesses an organizational scheme with letters and numbers. Sorting image uploads by letter, and then by number will allow me to print pdf files with the photos in their categorical order. 

Since the FileList itself doesn't require sorting, do you know if it might be possible to sort images immediately after they interact with a dropzone?

Comment: No, you only need to sort the list of the names, then retrieve the files from the FileList in that order.

Comment: I think I'm understanding that if I use the sorted list of names as the basis, I can use that to run a loop to check if there are matching file names in the file list. If at any point that function returns true, then I can push the value from the file list into its own array prior to executing the upload function. Even if I missed the mark, you gave me an idea to try and I certainly appreciate that! :)

Comment: Still, I would order the list server-side. Imagine a user loading his files in a couple of batches. Don't you want all his/her files sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your advice, Gerard! I ended up going with a button to sort the photos via multidimensional array based upon an id once the photos have been dropped in:

HTML:

```
<div class="dontprint">
            <input TYPE="button" onclick="sortFunction()" id="sortButton" class="sortButton" value=" Sort ">
            <input TYPE="button" value=" Shortcut to Print! " onclick="printpage()" />
            <INPUT TYPE="button" onclick="history.go(0)" value=" Clear ">
        </div>
```

Javascript:

```
/* ---------------------------Added to index.html as script tag------------------------ */
//Called on Button Click
function sortFunction() {

//Grab images, array them
const pulled = document.getElementsByClassName("postedImage");
imageObjects = Array.prototype.slice.call(pulled);
    
//Store current image ID & Image Source in their own Arrays
var imageIdArray = [];
var imageSrcArray = [];
   for (let i = 0; i < imageObjects.length; i++) {
        imageSrcArray.push(imageObjects[i].currentSrc);
        imageIdArray.push(imageObjects[i].id);
        }  

//Adopt a multidimensional Array to associate Image ID with Image Source 
var multiArray = [];
   for (var i=0; i<imageIdArray.length && i<imageSrcArray.length; i++)
       {multiArray[i] = [imageIdArray[i], imageSrcArray[i]];
            }

//Sort imageObjects (multiArray) alphanumerically
    multiArray.sort(function(a, b) {
        if(a[0] > b[0]) {return 1;}
        if (a[0] < b[0]) {return -1;}
            });

//Sort Image ID's
imageIdArray.sort();

//Change image name on page
   var currentName = document.getElementsByClassName('name');
   var currentLink = document.getElementsByClassName('postedImage');
       for (let i = 0; i < currentName.length; i++) {
           var newerName = imageIdArray[i];
           currentName[i].innerHTML = newerName;
           }

//Change image on page
//(Caution: Shuffles image sources when button is clicked more than once. Unsure why.)
   for (let i = 0; i < currentLink.length; i++) {
        var newLink = multiArray[i][1];
        currentLink[i].src = newLink;
        }
}

/*-----------------------------Update these parts in script.js--------------------------*/
uploadStarted:function(i, file, len){
            createImage(file);
            $.data(file).find('.name').text(file.name);
            //Give each file an ID representative of its name
            document.getElementById('sortId').id = file.name;
        },

        progressUpdated: function(i, file, progress) {
            $.data(file).find('.progress').width(progress);
            
        }
         
    });

//Gave the image an ID and a Class for easy grabbing
    var template = '<div class="preview">'+
                        '<span class="imageHolder">'+
                            '<img / id="sortId" class="postedImage">'+
                            '<span class="uploaded"></span>'+
                        '</span>'+
                        
                            '<div class="name"></div>'+
                            
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>';
};
```

In the event that someone knows how to fix an issue regarding sorting multidimensional arrays, I don't wish to shuffle the data url's with every button press. The arrays update with different image urls from the page any time the sort button is pressed. I'm also interested in knowing if Tif files could be supported by something like this, but I'll keep diving for info!